# How to integrate google cse in drupal6?

Tags: drupal-6, google-custom-search

I am new to drupal and I want to replace the search provided by drupal core with custom google search. How can I inteagrate google cse in drupal6?

Answer (score 2):

No, seriously, you should try google for this first.
"google cse drupal" gives the very first result - a link to [google_cse](http://drupal.org/project/google_cse) module.
you need to install and enable this module and follow instructions.

I suggest you to try installing 6.x-dev, because it is relatively fresh. If it has some critical bugs - you can use it as a starter point and general idea of how to implement cse at your site.

Regards, Slava.

Comment: Documentation says "On Drupal 6, the "Google CSE search" module is an optional glue module that integrates Google CSE with the core Search API. After enabling this module, search queries will be logged by the Search module and users can click between available search tabs: "Content", "Google", "Users", etc." The user is looking to replace default search block functionality to go straight to Google CSE tab. I'm looking for the same...